# Grouped column headings for a 2D plot

Tags: matlab, plot, label, matlab-figure, axis-labels

Is there any way to create a heatmap (or any plot) with grouped headings in MATLAB? In Excel you would use merge cells, see below.

[image: How I want it to look]

In MATLAB, when I use `\newline` in the header, it does not look very professional.

A minimum reproducible example:

```
A=rand(8);
heatmap(A);
set(gca,'XDisplayLabels',{'A\newlinecategory 1';'B';'A\newlinecategory 2';...
                'B';'A\newlinecategory 3';'B';'A\newlinecategory 4';'B'})
```

[image: Best I get]

How can I centre the second line?

Comment: Thanks for editing, I voted to reopen. Please do not repost questions, instead, edit the original one for improvement (like you did) and wait for the question to be reopened. If you think this isn't going fast enough, please ask a question about it on [meta]. (By "fast enough" I mean at least a day, don't edit and directly post on meta please)

Comment: Does adding spaces/tabs between `\newline` and `category` work? That way you could centre by hand. Alternatively, [`text()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) can write on the axis as well if you use the corresponding `x,y` pair; that you might even be able to automate using e.g. a handle to the axis and finding out the positions of the tick marks.